# Errors when transpiling ts files for an Angular2 application

Tags: typescript, angular

I try to use TypeScript with Angular. For this, I transpile my ts files using the tsc command and I have some errors. That said, the files are actually transpiled into JavaScript and I can make work my application but these errors are a bit strange....

Here is what I have:

```
app.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
app.ts(1,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
app.ts(13,7): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
```

Here is the content of the `tsd.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "angular2/angular2.d.ts": {
      "commit": "78ba6e41543e5ababbd1dda19797601be3c1f304"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the content of the `tsdconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "files" : [
    "app.ts",
    "typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

To compile, I execute the command: `tsc --watch *.ts`. My ts files are located at the root of my project.

Thanks very much for your help,
Thierry

Comment: Follow this [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/tsconfig.json).

Comment: If you use typescript for your gulpfile, you may have a look at  https://github.com/meandemo/ng2-demo.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you specify file(s) in tsc command, `tsconfig.json` file is **ignored**. You can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json). So you should invoke command: `tsc -w`. Second, you do not have to include typings in your files, they are just for intellisense in your editor(and angular2 includes its typings by default).